# Allow unnamed function with JSCS

Tags: javascript, couchdb, jscs

I have a CouchDB map.js file which expects code to be defined within an unnamed function:

```
function(doc){
      // do something
}
```

Because JSCS expects the function to be named, it says:

```
parseError: Unexpected token (
```

How can I ignore this error without changing my code?

I don't want to add inline rules like `// jscs:disable`

Comment: So basically the linter is telling you that you can't have anonymous functions? Maybe it's time to ignore the linter

Comment: Is that function standing alone by itself? Because that's a syntax error, which isn't a linter setting.

Comment: Well, JSCS isn't really a linter, it's just a style checker. It does have to lint to an extent but that's not it's main purpose. Sadly, this is the syntax that CouchDB uses even thought it's bad JS.

Comment: @adeneo it's not anonymous because it's not assigned to a variable or passed as a callback.

Comment: @MikeC Yes, it stands alone like that. CouchDB style.

Comment: Well, then as Mike said, it's invalid javascript, and would throw an error in any regular javascript file, so you can't reasonably expect that a ***linter*** understands that's it not javascript

Comment: @adeneo JSHint does allow you ignore this error but I'm using JSCS.